# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_A_iterator<_B>' to 'std::_A_iterator<_B>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got this bug in VisualStudio10, while trying to compile programm
(transfered from Unix to Windows env)

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_A_iterator<_B>' to 'std::_A_iterator<_B>'
```

it happens in line:

```
std::map<const char*, std::string>::iterator data = db.find(dbtype);
```

Comment: What is `PdoArguments::CharComparator`? How is `databases` instantiated?

Comment: Can you include the definition of `databases` ?

Comment: Please include the full text of the error message. The `with ... and` part is the important part of the error since it tells you what doesn't match. Otherwise the error merely says "Cannot initialize X(A) from X(A)` which on its face looks ridiculous. You need to see the two values of `A` for the error to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `databases` seams to be declared as `std::map<const char*, std::string, PdoArguments::CharComparator>` so use `std::map<const char*, std::string, PdoArguments::CharComparator>::iterator`

Comment: Or use `auto` - one of the few C++11 features MSVC++10 can actually do. ;)

Comment: He means auto it = databases.find(dbtype);